# call function from inside another Ajax function. works with Pure javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a quite rare problem, or I don't know since I am a beginner :)

I'm creating a DOM tree with ajax, the output is perfect, except that the functions I'm calling does not work. . If I create the same three with pure JavaScript. it actually calls the function. Well quite hard to explain, will show with some code.

```
function stickers(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add-new-sticker-btn').click(function() {
            $.get('xml/data.xml', function(data) {
                $('#page-content-wrapper').empty();

                $(data).find('car').each(function() {
                    var $car = $(this);
                    var sticker = '<div class="sticker">';
                    sticker += '<div class ="sticker-drag">' + '</div>';
                    sticker += '<textarea>' + $car.find('product').text() + '</textarea>';
                    sticker += '<div class="sticker-close">' + '</div>';

                    $('#page-content-wrapper').append(sticker);
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    }); 
    movewrap();  // <!-- this is the function that I'm trying to call.
}
```

but If I instead write the pure javascript

```
function stickers(){
    var sticker = createElementWithClass('div', 'sticker'),
    textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    var stickerDrag = createElementWithClass('div','sticker-drag')
    var stickerClose = createElementWithClass('div','sticker-close')

    sticker.appendChild(stickerDrag);
    sticker.appendChild(textArea);
    sticker.appendChild(stickerClose);

    document.getElementById('page-content-wrapper').appendChild(sticker);

    movewrap(); 
} // its calling the moveWrap function.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: in the second one its `movewrap()` and in the first its `moveWrap()`. is that a typo, or your problem?

Comment: @JeffShaver Hi. Oh its a typo, wrote the last part here instead of copy paste. will edit.

Comment: Try calling the function inside the success callback on the $.get call

Comment: Where are you defining `movewrap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the call to `moveWrap` at the end of your AJAX callback. Currently it's being called after the request is made, not after the response is received, and there won't be anything for it to do because the DOM elements aren't there yet.

Comment: Oooh. like a fu*** charm! thank you! tried to call it from the inside, but well.. not good enough :) 
Thanks again